# Gmail API sends email but some are never being received

Tags: python-2.7, gmail-api

I recently tried my hands at the new Gmail API. And all seems to work fine except one thing. My issue is as follows:

I working on a receptionist project that may need to generate more than one email in less than a minute during busy hours. So just for testing purposes I run the following code which works fine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  service = setup()      //Simply an helper function to do the basic credential check. Works fine!
  print('service:'+str(service))

  for counter in range(1, 10):
    print('Sending message '+ str(counter))
    message = create_message(<SENDER_EMAIL_ID>,<RECEIVER_EMAIL_ID>, "Email Number: "+ str(counter) , "Sample text")
    response = send_message(service, 'me' , message)
    print(response)
```

The setup() function is as follows:

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

Now, when I run the code say thrice consecutively in less than a minute, the code runs fine and I am able to see all the 27 emails in the sent folder of the SENDER_EMAIL_ID using a web browser. And thus Gmail API is sending all the messages through whenever a request is being made. However, only some of these emails are being received at the RECEIVER_EMAIL_ID and rest are just being dropped.

However, if I run the program with say 2-5 minutes delay then all the mails are being received.

I have no idea why this is.

Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Comment: I can imagine that the API is applying some kind of soft rate-limiting, so what I would suggest would be to compare the `response` given when calling `send_message()` versus the `response` for later calls of `get_message()`, and see how the responses differ between immediately sent, delayed and dropped emails.

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned. I am checking for the received mails directly using a browser. So I am just using the send_message(). Also the the response i get for every query being sent is as follows:


`Sent Message: {u'labelIds': [u'SENT'], u'id': u'157bce1438e5db28', u'threadId': u'157bce1438e5db28'}`

Comment: So, there are no errors on your response, it returns a [Users.messages resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) for all items on the loop, but only some were received by the recipient? Also, what do you mean by "dropped" - sending failed?

Comment: I will check User.messages.resource. But what I mean by "dropped" is that sending operation is successful in the terminal where the code is running at the moment and the sent mailbox of the SENDER_EMAIL_ID using the browser. However, the inbox of the RECEIVER_EMAIL_ID accessed using a browser does not reflect those emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expound more on @ken-y-n's response in the comments section, GMail API has [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota). Specifically for this product, Daily usage is about

- 1 Billion quota units / day
- 250 quota units / user / second

You may have encountered the `rateLimitExceeded` error during your tests.

Since you're sending emails thru a loop, it will cost you about 100 units when calling `send` (plus other costs depending on the methods you're calling). This is the reason why some emails seemed to be dropped. You can counter this by implementing exponential backoff on the messages that failed to send.

Another alternative instead of running it thru a loop, is to use [Batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) which groups your API calls together to reduce the number of HTTP connections your app making.

Comment: Thanks for that! I will look into the quota limits. However, i still wanted to confirm if it is normal to see all these burst emails in the sent folder using a browser for the SENDER_EMAIL_ID. Also, like I mentioned I did not receiveany different response for the emails that were dropped. My response for all the queryies sent was as follows:

`Sent Message: {u'labelIds': [u'SENT'], u'id': u'157bce1438e5db28', u'threadId': u'157bce1438e5db28'}
`